# saving xml data via php and using $vairables

Tags: php, xml

I have seen many questions on here regarding saving data to xml and I have managed to create a form that does so (thanks guys who asked and answered), there is only one minor blip

Here is the code so you know what I mean

```
<?php

function insertxml($Iname,$Iurl)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    //$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->load("bookmark.xml");
    // we want a nice output
    //$doc->formatOutput = true;

    $root = $doc->getElementsByTagName('bookmark')->item(0);

    $title = $doc->createElement('url', $Iurl);
    $domAttribute = $doc->createAttribute('name');
    $domAttribute->value = ('$Iname');
    $title->appendChild($domAttribute);
    $newtitle = $root->appendChild($title);

    echo 'Wrote: ' . $doc->save("bookmark.xml") . ' bytes'; // Wrote: 72 bytes

}    

$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Url = $_POST['url'];

insertxml($Name,$Url);
?>
```

and the form looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Xml Reader</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
URL: <input type="text" name="url"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the code works fine however when I put 'Test' in the name box and 'http://test.com' in the url box it comes out like this:

```
<url name="$Iname">http://test.com</url>
```

What i would like is

```
<url name="test">http://test.com</url>
<url name="(what ever name I put in the name box)">(what ever name I put in the url box)</url>
```

ultimatly what syntax should i put for the following?:

```
$title = $doc->createElement('url', $Iurl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the quotes from your variable

```
('$Iname')
```

should be

```
($Iname)
```

then remove the braces as they are not needed, too (there is nothing to group):

```
($Iname)
```

should be

```
$Iname
```

Comment: OF COURSE! thaks a lot, I'll take my foolish self else where :)

Comment: next step: remove the braces.